# Javascript complaining method not defined when it is indeed defined

Tags: javascript, function, public

This might be a very easy issue. I am still learning javascript and hoping I can get help for the issue below.

```
var hello = function()
{
    this.hey = function()
    {
        console.log("hey");
    }
    function init()
    {
        this.hey();
    }
    init();
}
var h = new hello();
```

The above code is complaining the method hey is not defined.
But if I do

```
var h = hello();
```

It didn't give any issues.

Why is the first one with the new that creates an object gave me error but the second one didn't? I need to create the object, thus I need to use the new keyword. How can I resolve the error I got from first one?

Comment: `this` is not defined inside `init`.

Comment: as @torazaburo said, you need to assign `this` to a variable first, so that you can call it inside of the scope of `init`

Comment: Related: [JavaScript “this” keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `hello` method with `new`, it will create a new instance of `hello` `function/class` and you will get a `this` as a context of `hello function`.

```
 var hello = function () {
     // this is an instance of hello class
     this.hey = function () {
         console.log("hey");
     }

     var _this = this; // creating this context of hello
     function init() {
         // this is a context of window here
         //this.hey(); // throws an error
         _this.hey(); // will execute
     }
     init();
 }
 var h = new hello(); // create a new instance/object of hello
```

While, when you simply calling it as a function `hello()`, you will get a `window` context inside `hello function`.

```
var hello = function () {
     // this is a context of window here
     this.hey = function () {
         console.log("hey");
     }

     function init() {
         // this is a context of window here
         this.hey(); // will execute
     }
     init();
 }
 var h = hello(); // calling a hello function
```

JSFIDDLE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8QN7W/